# How to connect remotly to the Hyper-v role on Windows 2008 Core without domain/workgroup auhtorisation

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I've configured my Windows Server 2008 to allow the remote management (using sconfig). 
I am connecting (with IP addres) using Windows Server 2008 (full version, where I've configured RSAT) and Server Manager (. 
I am using administrator account with the password on both systems. Firewalls are off.
When I try to use hyper-v role on server i got error:
Cannot connect to the RPC service on computer 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'. Make sure your RPC service is running.
I chcecked - RPC service is working.

Does anybody know where is the problem?

Comment: whats the rpc error code?  so can you do a "wmic /node:hyperserver-ipaddress os"   from the w2k8 server thats configured for rsat?

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not this is a hostname resolution issue. In a workgroup Hyper-V manager's "Connect to Server..." will NOT take a FQDN (and won't take an IP address) it must be a hostname only.

On the 2008 RSAT server in the hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) add the IP and hostname of the hyper-v core server and it will work.

Microsoft really should document some of this stuff better.

Answer (score 1):

check out this tool http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote

it helps configure authentication between the Hyper-V server and the client computer running RSAT if they are not domain-joined.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Remote Administration rules, you need to allow access to WMI on the Hyper-V server. 
Like this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes
```

Comment: All firewalls are turned off. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah. starting with a -1 for an obviously wrong answer.